# How to do event handling in Android similar to C#

Tags: android, events, c#-4.0, event-handling, backgroundworker

As I am aware we can do various types of event handling based on completion of a background thread on C# and I am also aware that we can use AsyncTask in android to handle background threads. but in their completion is it possible to do any event handling tasks on android. AFAIK onPostExecute can be used to throw any messages or UI updates but can I trigger an event at this point in the code? if so can someone provide me a small snippet or a tutorial. This is something that has been nagging for a quite a while.

Thanks

Comment: What do you consider to be "an event" that you would want to "trigger" from `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: Say I've got 3 different images to fetch and what I need to do is. I need to fetch one image first an on a successful image fetch completion I need to trigger an event to proceed to fetch the next image and so on. Hope this clarifies

Comment: What is "trigger an event" other than what the rest of us refer to as "programming", then? If you want something done in `onPostExecute()`, call a method to go do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger any UI events within a method on runonuithread() .